# How do i allow a levelling system to add roles at certain levels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've created a levelling system for my bot and I want it to add a role whenever you reach a certain level. I also want the roles and the level that they are applied at to be set with a command.
Here's my code

```
import itertools
import json
import random
import time
import traceback
import datetime
from functools import partial

import discord
from async_timeout import timeout
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from random import randint

class Levels(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.bot.loop.create_task(self.save_users())

        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            self.users = json.load(f)

    async def save_users(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(self.users, f, indent=4)

            await asyncio.sleep(5)

    def lvl_up(self, author_id, guild_id):
        cur_xp = self.users[guild_id][author_id]['exp']
        cur_lvl = self.users[guild_id][author_id]['level']

        if cur_xp >= round(2 * ((0.0002 * (cur_lvl ** 4)) - (0.0801 * (cur_lvl ** 3)) + (11.221 * (cur_lvl ** 2)) + (64.6 * cur_lvl) + 130.09)):
            self.users[guild_id][author_id]['level'] += 1
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('s.') is not True:
            if message.guild != None:
                f = open("users.json")
                self.users = json.load(f)
                if str(f"{message.guild.id}") not in self.users:
                    self.users[f"{message.guild.id}"] = {}
                    print(f"Guild file has been created for {message.guild.id}/{message.guild.name}")

                author_id = str(message.author.id)
                guild_id = str(message.guild.id)

                if str(f"{message.author.id}") not in self.users[f"{message.guild.id}"]:    
                    self.users[f"{message.guild.id}"][f"{message.author.id}"] = {}
                    self.users[guild_id][author_id]['level'] = 0
                    self.users[guild_id][author_id]['exp'] = 0
                    self.users[guild_id][author_id]["last_message"] = 0

                if time.time() - self.users[guild_id][author_id]["last_message"] > 5:
                    self.users[guild_id][author_id]['exp'] += random.randint(3,7)
                    self.users[guild_id][author_id]["last_message"] = time.time()

            if self.lvl_up(author_id, guild_id):
                await message.channel.send(f"""{message.author.mention} has leveled up to level {self.users[guild_id][author_id]['level']}!""")

    @commands.command()
    async def rank(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        member = ctx.author if not member else member
        member_id = str(member.id)
        guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)

        if not member_id in self.users[guild_id]:
            await ctx.send(f"That user has no experience")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(color=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name=f"Rank - {member}", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Level", value=self.users[guild_id][member_id]['level'])
            embed.add_field(name="Experience", value=self.users[guild_id][member_id]['exp'])

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)  

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Levels(bot))
    print('Levels Loaded')
```

I'm fairly new to this and i've tried making a .json file to store the set roles and levels for each server but it didn't work. I've also looked around and cant seem to find anything related to what im doing so any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: `levels for each server but it didn't work.` why exactly? a simple lookup table would do the job `level<>role`

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work, it just didnt

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it out but you are looking for something that will look like this:

```
# You can save this as a class variable
roles = {1: "Noobie", 10: "Experienced", 30: "master"}

# Add this to the function that checks if the user has leveled up
for level, role in roles.items():
    if user_level == level:
        await user.add_roles(role, reason=None, atomic=True)
        # Adds the desired role
```

Im not sure if thats the best way to do it but u can certainly try.